# how to create multiple list array

Tags: arrays, json, api

I get **Alphabet** and list **Country** from query, how can I make some JSON like this?
I have no idea for this one. How can I create some JSON like that?

```
> List=[
>     {Alphabet:'B',
>     Country:[
>       {name: 'Belgia'}
>     ]},
>     {Alphabet:'I',
>     Country:[
>       {name: 'Indonesia'}
>     ]},
>     {Alphabet:'N',
>     Country:[
>       {name: 'Namibia'}
>     ]},
>     {Alphabet:'O',
>     Country:[
>       {name: 'Ohio'}
>     ]},
>     {Alphabet:'T',
>     Country:[
>       {name: 'Turki'},
>       {name: 'Tunisia'}
>     ]},
>     {Alphabet:'Y',
>     Country:[
>       {name: 'Yaman'},
>     ]}    ];
```

I have some model like this

```
> public class ListCountry {
>     private String Alphabet;
>     List<ListCountryObj> List;
>     
>     public void setAlphabet(String Alphabet){this.Alphabet= Alphabet;}
>     public void setList(List<ListCountryObj> List){this.List  = List;}
>     
>     public String getAlphabet(){return this.Alphabet;}
>     public List<ListCountryObj> getList() {return List;} }
```

and this

```
> public class ListCountryObj {
>     private String country;
>     
>     public void setCountry(String country){this.country = country;}
>     public String getCountry(){return this.country;} }
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Create an empty array
2. Map over results
3. Get character at position 0
4. Check array for object with Alphabet == that character
5. If doesn’t exist create object {Alphabet: A, Countries [“America”]}
6. If it does exist simply push the country onto the countries array.

Comment: for point 5, I think it should automatic add if I add some data in database. sorry I have add some more information om my question

Answer (score 0):

```
List<Map<String, List<String>
```

Create two models with one having the Map object by extending Map. And other is list of that Object.

```
Class A extends map { // add all the override methods

 // annotate with name you want in json
  String key;
  // annotate with name you want in json
  List<String> value
  }

  Class B {
    List<A> listOfA;
   }
```

Make sure you build the object A and to Object B.